# Microsoft oauth email sending issue in entra admin center

Tags: spring-boot, email, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

as i need to send email from microsoft o behalf of user who gave me mail sending permission
below are the steps which i have followed

1. created application in entra.microsoft.com
2. added platform configuration as web and SPA
3. Added permission for profile and mail for both application and delegated.

Now on code side followed below steps
4. called below api from browser

> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&response_mode=query&scope=User.Read](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&response_mode=query&scope=User.Read)
> Mail.Read Mail.Send openid profile offline_access

5. then getting code in query parameter
6. used that code from step 5 in below API

> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)
> where below is body in x-www-form-urlencoded format
>  client_id,
> scope=User.Read Mail.Read Mail.Send openid profile offline_access,
> code, redirect_uri, grant_type= authorization_code, client_secret.

in resopnse i am getting

> token_type,scope,expires_in,ext_expires_in,access_token,refresh_token,id_token.

7. Now i am using access_token from step 6 to send mail with below api
   `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + fromEmailAddress + "/sendMail`

but it always says

```
{ "error": { "code": "ErrorInvalidUser", 
"message": "The requested user is invalid." }
```

Below are the images for my application on entra admin of microsoft
[image]
[image]
can someone help me to solve this issue 
or suggest me proper way to perform this task
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are now using auth code flow to generate an access token and use it to call graph API, so could you pls test if you could send mails successfully with url `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail`? If not, could you pls try to call api `Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` to see if the token is correct? I deduce that you might get correct response from the get request but  still get the same error from the send mail request.

Comment: Pls be sure you'r using an account e.g `user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com` to have the authcode,and make sure you have a correct license e.g M365 E5 on this account. Not each account is able to send the email. Graph API is used for accounts in the tenants, you could use gmail account to register into the tenant, but that will make you have an account like `xx_gmail.com#EXT#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`, you are actually trying to use this account to send email, which isn't able to send email without a correct [license](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/office365-plans-and-pricing).

Answer (score 0):

> The error "***The requested user 'UPN' is invalid***" usually occurs
> if you are generating access token for single tenant and passing other tenant or Microsoft account user to send mail.

I generated **auth-code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=User.Read Mail.Read Mail.Send openid profile offline_access
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated **access token** by using parameters like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:User.Read Mail.Read Mail.Send openid profile offline_access
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I tried to send mail with **another tenant/Microsoft account user,** got the **same error** as below:

[image]

**To resolve the error**, make sure to pass the user is residing in your tenant by executing the query `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

- **Otherwise**, if you want to pass another tenant user, register application as multitenant and use **`organizations`** endpoint to generate code and access token.
- If you want to pass any other tenant user or Microsoft account user then register application by selecting "*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts*" and use **`common`** endpoint.
- Make sure the user has required [license](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/office365-plans-and-pricing) to send mail

Now to send mail, **I passed the user in the Azure AD tenant, and I am able to send mail successfully** like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/sendMail

{
"message": {
"subject": "Meet for lunch?",
"body": {
"contentType": "Text",
"content": "The new cafeteria is open."
},
"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "user2@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
}
}
]
},
"saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

[image]